# How to change Format "Hours" to "hour : minutes" in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

hi everyone i have one columns is Duration columns, the column is in hour format, and I want to convert it to "hour:minutes" format, what formula can I use in excel?

i use =TEXT(A1/24,"hh:mm")

Comment: Simple: `=<cell>/24`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=A1/24
```

and format as follows:

[image]

Note the brackets in the formatting:

```
[hh]:mm
```

Comment: I was not aware of square bracket `[ ]`. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide hours by 24. Try below formula-

```
=TEXT(A1/24,"hh:mm")
```

Check this article from exceljet.net [Convert decimal hours to Excel time.](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-decimal-hours-to-excel-time)

From ***@Gary's Student*** answer, you can also use same format with text function.

```
=TEXT(A1/24,"[hh]:mm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, but I wanted to offer an alternative that does not involve formatting the cell (which may or may not be desirable, although it probably usually is the best way TBH).

The following formula splits the hours and minutes:

`=FLOOR(S10,1) & ":" & (S10-FLOOR(S10,1))*60`